# How to disable html table row

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If I click 3 times html table same row means.. I want to disable/hide that row.. that click count only reset when page reload.. using only pure javascript

My code:

```js
                                                               window.onload=function found(row) {
            var table=document.getElementById("main");
            var rows = table.rows;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                 rows[i].onclick = (function() { // closure
                    var cnt = i; // save the counter to use in the function
                         return function() {
                           var result = this.cells[i];
                           alert("You want to choose "+result.innerHTML);
                         }
                   })(i);
               }
           }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
  <body>

<table id="main"><tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the number of counts remaining in the closure you create on each `onclick` handler. Then, when this count reaches 0, you hide the row. Something like this:

```
var numberOfClicks = 3;
var table=document.getElementById("main");
var rows = table.rows;
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].onclick = (function(cnt) { // closure
        return function() {
            if (--cnt == 0) {
                this.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    })(numberOfClicks);
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pfqany5j/)

Comment: Yeah its working... But i want each time click show alert that value.. if i click third time means it will show that value then only hide...

Comment: What value do you mean? The `cnt` value?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload=function found(row) {
    var table=document.getElementById("main");
    var rows = table.rows;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].cnt = 0;
        rows[i].onclick = (function() {
            this.cnt ++;
            alert (this.cnt);
            if (this.cnt == 3){
                this.style.display = 'none';
            }           
        });
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Dan

Comment: Yeah its working... But i want each time click show alert that value.. if i click third time means it will show that value then only hide...

Comment: after  
    this.cnt ++; 
put 
    alert(this.cnt);